# Decoupling in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

my problem is that I want some code ( 1 bundle ) to be on 1 server, and some code ( another bundle ) on another server, both servers would use the same database, and to properly decouple the code, I just want to get entities from the database based on some information that I would just send from 1 server to another.

Let us say that I have a user on 1 side, and on the other side I have a customer ( probably a bad example, but just go with it ), customer does not know about the user at all, nor does the user know about the customer, but I want to update user's data based on some information that I use in the customer ( or something like that )

Is it at all possible ?

Thanks

Edit: Both User and Customer are classes/bundles, does not matter which are they, since they are still on separate servers, I want the Customer class/bundle to update the User class/bundle without it knowing the structure of the User class/bundle.

Edit2:

Let us imagine, that I am using the awful bundle called FOSUserBundle on 1 server ( an actual physical server ), and on the same server I have registration, login, whatever the user needs to operate, there is also an Account Entity:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="accounts")
 */
class Account
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="File", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $files;
}
```

the User in this Entity is of the FOSUserBundle, and I want the File to remain completely separate from this Entity, File is in the database, created on the other server, by a different bundle. To be able to update a specific Account, I need to send the ID of the Account to the other server, and based on that ID I want to update the correct Account, now then, this server does not know the implementation of File, and the other server does not know the implementation of Account, they both have access to the database though, so can I do that ?

Comment: Kind of sounds like a REST like approach?  On the customer site you can use curl to access user resources on the other site.

Comment: But I am not trying to connect to the other server to grab the resources, the resources are going to be sent with http POST or GET to the other server, and with those resources I want to update the database.

Comment: Still confused.  PUT /users/42 with a json payload will update the user assuming the user server has a REST like interface.  Maybe someone else understands.

Comment: I may have goofed, what I meant in my example is that User and Customer are bundles, or classes, and I want the Customer class/bundle to update User class/bundle without them knowing about each other.

Comment: All I can suggest is adding some code to your question.  The way you are using the server/database/bundle/class terms is not making sense to me.

Comment: Updated. Some code included.

Comment: Not with Doctrine 2.  You can't create a relation between entities without doctrine knowing all the mapping information for both entities.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there could be kind of a solution, to just generate the entity and use that, but that still requires the implementation to be there, how the hell do you actually decouple anything in php then ?

No matter, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You decouple in php pretty much the same way you decouple in any other language.

Consider a referee assigning system.  We have:

```
class GameReferee
{
  private $game;
  private $refereeName;
  private $refereeBadge;
  private $refereeGuid;  // Globally unique identifier
}
```

We store the referee's name and badge since they show up on game schedules.  But let's say we need to contact a referee because a game has changed.  We can:

```
$event = new FindRefereeContactInfoEvent($refereeGuid);
$eventDispatcherer->dispatch($event);
$contactInfo = $event->getContactInfo();
```

The game application neither knows not cares where the person's contact information is kept.  It could be in a person bundle within the same application.  Or it could be on a different server with a completely different database.  The event listener acts as a middle man.

There are of course a number of other approaches to decoupling.  Take your pick.

Comment: I know the normal decoupling, my problem is pretty different ( at least I think it is ), because Doctrine requires the implementation of the entity for it to work, which means the implementation has to be on the same server, so I just decided to keep a kind of a bridge entity on both servers, so that one server can first put some part of it in place, and the other server will fill in the rest, I think that is the way to go. Thanks for the answer anyway, it might help someone.

Comment: You were right Cerad, this answer does not actually answer my question, but Your first comment does, it is exactly what I ended up doing, the server just passes information via Curl POST request back to Main Server's API, to inform it about what happend. Could You add something about using Curl, REST or APIs here in Your answer, so I can accept it ?